# Check two binary search trees have the same in-order traversal

Tags: arrays, algorithm, tree

Check two binary search trees have the same in-order traversal. My naive approach is to in-order traverse the given two trees and copy each element onto an array separately, then check these two arrays are the same. But I feel like we should be able to just copy elements from one tree onto an array and use that array to verify the other tree on the fly, instead of using two arrays. Or better yet, there may be a way to do it without using any array. My code is following, not sure if my implementation of hasSameInOrder() is correct. Or could we do it without using any array? 
Please note that two trees having the same in-order traversal mean if you copy the elements onto an array when in-order traversing, the two resulted array should have the same value. So they don't necessarily have the same structure in order to have the same in-order traversal.

```
public boolean checkTwoBSTHaveSameInOrder(Node n1, Node n2) {
   LinkedList<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
   inOrder(n1, buffer);
   hasSameInOrder(n2, queue)
   return queue==null? false: true;
}
public void inOrder(Node node, LinkedList<Node> queue) {
   if (node==null)
       return;
   inOrder(node.left, queue);
   queue.add(node);
   inOrder(node.right, queue);
}
public void hasSameInOrder(Node node, LinkedList<Node> queue) {
   if (node==null)
      return;
   hasSameInOrder(n2.left, queue));
   if (queue==null)
      return;
   else {
      if (node!=queue.poll())
           queue=null;
   }
   hasSameInOrder(n2.right, queue));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do it in more better space complexity O(1)
We can use  Morris Traversal to iterate over the trees and compare the values element by element.

I am assuming both tree have same number of nodes for the below implementation.

```
  bool isSame(root1, root2){
    while(root1!=null && root2!=null){
        while(root1->left!=NULL){
            auto maxleft = getmaxnode(root1->left);
            maxleft->right = root1;
            auto next = root1->left;
            root1->left = NULL;
            root1 = next;
        }
        while(root2->left!=NULL){
            auto maxleft = getmaxnode(root2->left);
            maxleft->right = root2;
            auto next = root2->left;
            root2->left = NULL;
            root2 = next;
        }
        if(root1->val != root2->val) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two tree which in order are same as follow

1. InOrder function tree1 will populate queue
2. CheckInOrder function will compare the value with second tree
3. if there is a mismatch return false

```
    /*
      Tree 1           Tree 2
         5                3
        / \              / \
       3   7            1   6
      /   /                / \
     1   6                5   7
    [1,3,5,6,7]      [1,3,5,6,7]
    */
    
    #include <iostream>
    #include <queue>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    struct NODE {
        NODE() {
            val = 0;
            left = NULL;
            right = NULL;
        }
    
        NODE(int n) {
            val = n;
            left = NULL;
            right = NULL;
        }
        int val;
        NODE* left;
        NODE* right;
    };
    
    void InOrder(NODE* root, queue<int>& q)
    {
        if (root == NULL)
            return;

        InOrder(root->left, q);
        q.push(root->val);
        InOrder(root->right, q);
    }
        
    bool CheckInOrder(NODE* root, queue<int>& q)
    {
        if (root == NULL)
            return true;
        if (!CheckInOrder(root->left, q))
            return false;
        if (!q.empty() && root->val == q.front())
            q.pop();
        else
            return false;
    
        return CheckInOrder(root->right, q);
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        NODE* tree1;
        NODE* tree2;
        queue<int> tq;
    
        tree1 = new NODE(5);
        tree1->left = new NODE(3);
        tree1->right = new NODE(7);
        tree1->left->left = new NODE(1);
        tree1->right->left = new NODE(6);
    
        tree2 = new NODE(3);
        tree2->left = new NODE(1);
        tree2->right = new NODE(6);
        tree2->right->left = new NODE(5);
        tree2->right->right = new NODE(7);
    
        InOrder(tree1, tq);
        if (CheckInOrder(tree2, tq) && tq.empty())
            cout << "TRUE";
        else
            cout << "FALSE";
    }
```

Comment: An explanation why this code solves OP's issue would improve this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a single loop in the iterative implementation of the Inorder Traversal for both trees.You will need two added stacks(read queue) to keep track of the match. Obviously this is not going to improve the worst case asymptotic time which is impossible to better, but the on hand approach ensures a reasonable time gain on a random pair of trees.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single array in following manner :-

```
int count =0;
int[] arr;

void inorder(node*p) {

  if(p!=null) {

       inorder(p->left);
       arr[count++] = p->data;
       inorder(p->right);
  }  

}

int c2 =0;
boolean checkSame(node*p,int[] arr) {

    if(p!=null) {
       boolean t = true;  
       t = checkSame(p->left,arr);
       if(c2+1>=count||arr[c2++]!=p->data) {

           return(false);  
       } 
       return(t&&checkSame(p->right,arr));

    }

}
```

Comment: Then it would be the same as my approach using a linked list

Comment: Than using a linked list? Well, using a linked list vs using an array would be the same I think. Unless we can do it without using any buffer.

Comment: I meant you "cant do better"

Answer (score 0):

If we can restructure the tree, then transfer both the trees to left or right skewed format, then do the comparison in a single traversal  [Skewed Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15hyu.jpg)

Else we can avoid the cost by transferring only one tree to the skewed format and compare it while doing inorder traversal of other.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do it without using array. We can achieve it using Threads. We can interact among threads using wait() and notify(). Trigger recursive inorder traversal in both trees in separate threads. Read first element in one tree and wait for other tree to read its first element. Compare these elements and proceed to remaining elements. You can follow below sample code.

```
//common lock for both threads
Object lock = new Object();

// flag to check if traverseFirstTree can come out of wait or not
boolean proceedFirst = false;

// flag to check if traverseSecondTree can come out of wait or not
boolean proceedSecond = false;

//value of current element in second BinarySearchTree
int element;

boolean identicalInorderOrNot(BST bst1, BST bst2){
  //check if no. of elements in both are same. If not return false
  if (bst1.size() != bst2.size()){
    return false;
  } 
  Thread thread = new Thread (new Runnable(){
    void run(){
      traverseSecondTree(bst2);
    }
  });
  //it does not matter if traverseSecondTree gets executed before traverseFirstTree(), as we have check for this condition
  thread.start()
  return traverseFirstTree(bst1);
}

private boolean traverseFirstTree(BST node){
  if(bst1 == null){
    return true;
  }
  if (!traverseFirstTree(node.left)){
    return false;
  }
  synchronized(lock){
    proceedFirst = false;
    while (!proceedFirst){
      proceedSecond = true;
      wait();
    }
  notify()
  }
  //check if root data of bst1 is same as current element of bst2
  if (node.data != element){
    return false;
  }
  return traverseFirstTree(node.right)
}

private void traverseSecondTree(BST node){
  if (node ==  null){
    return true;
  }
  traverseSecondTree(node.left)
  synchronized(lock){
    while (!proceedSecond){
      wait();
    }
    element = node.data;
    proceedFirst = true;
    proceedSecond = false;
    notify();

  traverseSecondTree(node.right)
}
```